# Need my GUI to read from a JTextField and show in a JPanel

Tags: java

I have added an action listener to the text field. When the btnReadString (Button Read String) is pressed the program should read what is on the text field and show on the JPanel. but nothing shows on the panel.

```
stringTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void stringTextField (java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==btnReadString) //when the button is pressed
        {
            String stringParameter = stringTextField.getText(); //gets the text and puts it on this string called "stringParameter"
            textPane.setText(stringParameter);//the JPanel is set to what is on the string. 
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: 1. You "action" functionality should go in the `actionPerformed` method; 2. You probably want the `ActionListener` attached to the `JButton` and not the field, as you're relying on it and not the field to generate the event

Comment: Using NetBeans for Swing GUI building is very useful

Comment: @StarCoder Unless you actually understand how the API works, form editors tend to teach bad habits - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer True, but if your just getting started with it, it's nice to have.

Comment: @StarCoder Even as a seasoned developer, I found it encouraged me to do things that I wouldn't have done if I'd done if I was using just code - can't imagine what some one who as little experience would get themselves into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the `ActionListener` to the text field. So the event source is never going to be the button and hence, the code is never going to execute. What you want is to add the `ActionListener` to the `JButton`.

Also, the `actionPerformed()` is there for a reason. All your 'action' code goes inside this method.

So your code should look like this:

```
btnReadString.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String stringParameter = stringTextField.getText();
    textPane.setText(stringParameter);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The functionality for the `ActionListener` should go in the `actionPerformed` method, as nothings calling the `stringTextField` method...

```
stringTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==btnReadString) //when the button is pressed
        {
            String stringParameter = stringTextField.getText(); //gets the text and puts it on this string called "stringParameter"
            textPane.setText(stringParameter);//the JPanel is set to what is on the string. 
        }
    }
});
```

But, based on the code, the `ActionListener` should be attached to the `btnReadString` and not the field, as the above logic will never result in anything been executed (as the source of the event will never be `btnReadString`)

```
btnReadString.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String stringParameter = stringTextField.getText(); //gets the text and puts it on this string called "stringParameter"
        textPane.setText(stringParameter);//the JPanel is set to what is on the string. 
    }
});
```

I would suggest having a closer look at [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details